# Sourcset main not found while trying to send through sendgrid

Tags: android, firebase, sendgrid

Followed a few youtube tutorials to send emails to user on sendgrid,but keep getting this error when I try to run them in my android studio project.
Any ideas?

```
 * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    > Could not create task ':app:SendEmail.main()'.
       > SourceSet with name 'main' not found.
```

My method is below.

```
    private Task<String> sendMail(String eventText, String action) {
        FirebaseFunctions functions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();
// Create the arguments to the callable function.
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("event", eventText);
        data.put("action", action);
        data.put("push", true);
        return functions
                .getHttpsCallable("sendMail")
                .call(data)
                .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                        String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
                        return result;

                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've actually built a Sendgrid library for Android using Sendgrid's latest API.

https://github.com/Jakebreen/android-sendgrid

implementation 'uk.co.jakebreen:android-sendgrid:1.2.2'

I maintain it so if you have any questions log an issue on the github page.